# Returning Two Promises With Angularjs, How To Chain So UI Has $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, http-get

My UI was breaking because my second promise had a dependency in the first promise that wouldn't resolve quick enough. Therefore I took the 2nd promise and nested it in the 1st promise like so:

```
 csRepo.getSet(setID).then(
        function (val) {
            $scope.dataSet= val;

            csRepo.getInfoInSet(setID).then(
                function (val) {
                 $scope.dataSet.InfoOfSet = val;
                 $scope.$apply();
                 })
                .catch(function (reason) {
               throw "getInfoSet:" + reason;
                 });
            $scope.$apply();
        })
        .catch(function (reason) {
            throw "getSet() :" + reason;
        });
```

This did the work, but I believe best practice is to chain the two "then" together. Is this true and if so can someone refactor my code sample to show this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can call both the methods independently as `setID` is available from closure of the function calls but if you want to call `csRepo.getInfoInSet` only after `csRepo.getSet` you can  do it like this:

```
 csRepo.getSet(setID).then(
    function (val) {
        $scope.dataSet= val;
        return setID;
    })
    .then(csRepo.getInfoInSet)
    .then(function (val) {
       $scope.dataSet.InfoOfSet = val;
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
       throw reason;
    })
```

You don't need to call the `$scope.$apply` everytime, as it has performance impacts as well. You can use `$q.all` to call both the methods parallely and combine the promises. Refer this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: how is getInfoInSet(setID) getting the setID?

Comment: Its because of the chaining of `then`. The return value of previous `then` is the parameter in next callback. Also accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Oh yeah lol, if I'm not using $q.all, for the time being where can I apply the $scope.$apply()?

Comment: You won't need to explicitly call `$scope.$apply`. It triggers the digest cycle immediately. Most of the times you won't need to as angular takes care of that. but if you definitely want to you can use `.finally` chained method